# Tensorflow's variable_scope() and tf.AUTO_REUSE will not reuse variables in a for loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, scope, conv-neural-network

I want to pass several different inputs into a reusable tensorflow architecture (decoder). To do this, I use a for loop in which I feed my inputs into the model. However, I fail to reuse the layer variables and instead, create variables for each loop iteration. Assume this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

for i in range(5):
    decoder(input=input, is_training=is_training)
```

while the decoder is:

```
def decoder(self, input, is_training):

    with tf.variable_scope("physics", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
         latent = tf.expand_dims(latent, axis=1)
         latent = tf.expand_dims(latent, axis=1)

         x = latent

         """ Layer 1 """
         x = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(x, filters=256, kernel_size=2, strides=1, activation='relu', padding='valid', name="transpose1_1", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)
         x = tf.layers.batch_normalization(x, training=is_training, name="transpose_bn_1_1")

         """ Layer 2 """
         x = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(x, filters=256, kernel_size=2, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='valid', name="transpose1_2", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)
         x = tf.layers.batch_normalization(x, training=is_training, name="transpose_bn_1_2")

         ...
```

If I now output the variables immediately after the loop with

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint([n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node])
```

I get the following output, indicating that I am not sharing my variables among the loop iterations:

```
 'physics/transpose1_1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/shape',
 'physics/transpose1_1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/min',
 'physics/transpose1_1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/max',
 'physics/transpose1_1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/RandomUniform',
 'physics/transpose1_1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/sub',
 'physics/transpose1_1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform/mul',
 'physics/transpose1_1/kernel/Initializer/random_uniform',
 'physics/transpose1_1/kernel',
 'physics/transpose1_1/kernel/Assign',
 'physics/transpose1_1/kernel/read',
 'physics/transpose1_1/bias/Initializer/zeros',
 'physics/transpose1_1/bias',
 'physics/transpose1_1/bias/Assign',
 'physics/transpose1_1/bias/read',
 'physics/transpose1_1/Shape',
 'physics/transpose1_1/strided_slice/stack',
 'physics/transpose1_1/strided_slice/stack_1',
 'physics/transpose1_1/strided_slice/stack_2',
 'physics/transpose1_1/strided_slice',
 'physics/transpose1_1/strided_slice_1/stack',
 'physics/transpose1_1/strided_slice_1/stack_1',
 'physics/transpose1_1/strided_slice_1/stack_2',
 'physics/transpose1_1/strided_slice_1',
 'physics/transpose1_1/strided_slice_2/stack',
 'physics/transpose1_1/strided_slice_2/stack_1',
 'physics/transpose1_1/strided_slice_2/stack_2',
 'physics/transpose1_1/strided_slice_2',
 'physics/transpose1_1/mul/y',
 'physics/transpose1_1/mul',
 'physics/transpose1_1/add/y',
 'physics/transpose1_1/add',
 'physics/transpose1_1/mul_1/y',
 'physics/transpose1_1/mul_1',
 'physics/transpose1_1/add_1/y',
 'physics/transpose1_1/add_1',
 'physics/transpose1_1/stack/3',
 'physics/transpose1_1/stack',
 'physics/transpose1_1/conv2d_transpose',
 'physics/transpose1_1/BiasAdd',
 'physics/transpose1_1/Relu',
 ...
 'physics_4/transpose1_1/Shape',
 'physics_4/transpose1_1/strided_slice/stack',
 'physics_4/transpose1_1/strided_slice/stack_1',
 'physics_4/transpose1_1/strided_slice/stack_2',
 'physics_4/transpose1_1/strided_slice',
 'physics_4/transpose1_1/strided_slice_1/stack',
 'physics_4/transpose1_1/strided_slice_1/stack_1',
 'physics_4/transpose1_1/strided_slice_1/stack_2',
 'physics_4/transpose1_1/strided_slice_1',
 'physics_4/transpose1_1/strided_slice_2/stack',
 'physics_4/transpose1_1/strided_slice_2/stack_1',
 'physics_4/transpose1_1/strided_slice_2/stack_2',
 'physics_4/transpose1_1/strided_slice_2',
 'physics_4/transpose1_1/mul/y',
 'physics_4/transpose1_1/mul',
 'physics_4/transpose1_1/add/y',
 'physics_4/transpose1_1/add',
 'physics_4/transpose1_1/mul_1/y',
 'physics_4/transpose1_1/mul_1',
 'physics_4/transpose1_1/add_1/y',
 'physics_4/transpose1_1/add_1',
 'physics_4/transpose1_1/stack/3',
 'physics_4/transpose1_1/stack',
 'physics_4/transpose1_1/conv2d_transpose',
 'physics_4/transpose1_1/BiasAdd',
 'physics_4/transpose1_1/Relu',
```

What is going on here? Shouldn't the `tf.AUTO_REUSE` flag allow me to first initialize my `decoder` when `i==0` and for all iterations `i>0` reuse my variables? The above reoccurs for every layer I have in my decoder.

I am using TensorFlow version `1.12.0`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've already reused variables in a for loop. Nodes of graphs are not equivalent to `Variable`. The following example has multiple nodes but only one `Variable`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.Variable([2.0],name='a')
b = a+1
print([n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node])

['a/initial_value', 'a', 'a/Assign', 'a/read', 'add/y', 'add']
```

You should use other ways to see you variables in your code.

1.adding `if "Variable" in n.op` at the end of the comprehension

```
print([n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node if "Variable" in n.op])

['a']
```

2.Using `tf.global_variables()`.

```
print(tf.global_variables())

[<tf.Variable 'a:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>]
```

So you should do as follow in your code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def decoder(latent, is_training):
    with tf.variable_scope("physics", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
        x = latent
        """ Layer 1 """
        x = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(x, filters=256, kernel_size=2, strides=1, activation='relu', padding='valid', name="transpose1_1", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)
        x = tf.layers.batch_normalization(x, training=is_training, name="transpose_bn_1_1")
        """ Layer 2 """
        x = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(x, filters=256, kernel_size=2, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='valid', name="transpose1_2", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)
        x = tf.layers.batch_normalization(x, training=is_training, name="transpose_bn_1_2")

for i in range(5):
    decoder(latent=tf.ones(shape=[64,7,7,256]) , is_training=True)

print([n.name  for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node if "Variable" in n.op])
# print(tf.global_variables())

['physics/transpose1_1/kernel', 'physics/transpose1_1/bias', 'physics/transpose_bn_1_1/gamma', 'physics/transpose_bn_1_1/beta', 'physics/transpose_bn_1_1/moving_mean', 'physics/transpose_bn_1_1/moving_variance', 'physics/transpose1_2/kernel', 'physics/transpose1_2/bias', 'physics/transpose_bn_1_2/gamma', 'physics/transpose_bn_1_2/beta', 'physics/transpose_bn_1_2/moving_mean', 'physics/transpose_bn_1_2/moving_variance']
```

Answer (score 0):

TF builds a variable name from the name of the layer. Then, when it tries to create a variable it will check if variable already exists. If it does, it will throw you an exception, unless you specify that variables can be reused.

To fix your code you need to use the same name in layers that should share the variables. Same is stated in [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/conv2d_transpose):

```
reuse: Boolean, whether to reuse the weights of a previous layer by the same name.
```

Further, to debug your code and make sure that your vars are pointing to the same place you can simply remove `reuse` parameter and make sure that an exception appears when you try to run your model.

Comment: I don't know what you're suggesting. Giving each layer a unique name (which is what I did) will not solve the issue alone. As for using the flag to check for exceptions: yes, that's a good tip! Thanks

Comment: The `documentation` link is now wrong.